# "ul li:before" and "display:block" combination - text pushed to next line

Tags: html, css, block

I've been using the following HTML and CSS code for a nav menu on the left for the better part of a year without problems - except that not the `display: block` functionality doesn't work on `ul li a`. The text gets pushed down a line, with only the before arrows remaining in place, no matter what I do.

On `ul li` it's no problem, but it would be more practical to have the link itself extend throughout a block.

Anyone an idea as to the solution?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navmenu_left_wrapper">
<nav>
<div class="navmenu_left">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Front page</a></li>
    <li><a href="intro.php">Introduction</a></li>
  </ul>
</div> 
</nav>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navmenu_left_wrapper {
padding-bottom: 1px;
background-color: #DDD;
text-align: left;
overflow: visible;
width: 145px;
text-align: left;
} 

.navmenu_left {
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
font-size: 12px;        
font-family: 'oswald-regular', 'Times New Roman';
border: 1px dotted #000;
} 

.navmenu_left ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: block; 
}

.navmenu_left ul li:before {
content: "\00BB \0020";
padding-right: 2px;
}

.navmenu_left ul li {
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding-left: 4px;
list-style: none;
background: #F2F2F2;
text-align: left;               
text-decoration: none;          
height: 18px;       
}

.navmenu_left ul li:hover {
background: #CCCCFF;            
}

.navmenu_left ul li a {
color: #000;                    
width: 135px;
display: block; /* <----- Doesn't work. Text to next line, underneath "before" arrow. -------- */
}
```

Comment: I think you need inline-block => http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/   && http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/  if  not bringing a solution, @tag me

Comment: I'll take a look at the articles, but did already experiment with inline-block in all possible locations. Suspect it's something else.

Comment: let me take a closer look, a moment please :)

Comment: if i remove display: block; .navmenu_left ul li a i look like you wanna have it (i think)

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdgLVZ <= this ??

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `display: inline-block` as others have stated in the comments. The problem is your `a` is too wide at 135px and is overflowing the container. The whitespace will cause it to wrap by default.

You can either reduce the width of the `a` or add `white-space: nowrap;` to the `.navmenu_left ul li` CSS

`white-space` property - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/msj5wcgw/3/

You can even set it to show ellipsis if it overflows via `overflow: ellipsis`

If you want the >> to be clickable, you can add this hack to `.navmenu_left ul li a`:

```
padding-left: 1rem;
margin-left: -1rem;
```

Comment: I'm going to try it out tonight, but a is certainly not too wide. I can reduce to 50px complete with the text and it gives me the same effect: The text is pushed one line lower and actually disappears behind the nav div  in question. Without ':before' no issues.

Comment: You still need to set display to 'inline-block'.  I put your example in a jsfiddle, updated the style for '.navmenu_left ul li a' by adding 'display: inline-block' and  reduce the width to 128px, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was a combination of two settings:

```
.navmenu_left ul li a {
color: #000;                    
width: 128px;          /* ">>" symbol is not part of the overall   width of the <li> element. */
display: inline-block; /* that explains also why `inline-block` is needed and not just `block`.
}
```

Comment: Your solution looks similar to the one listed above.